# email input field is not remembering last emails

Tags: html, css, autocomplete

I have an input field with type `email`.

```
<input name="email" type="email" autocomplete />
```

and it is not inside `<form>`,

the issue is, field is not remembering and not offering former email entries.

how can I activate this? I am using chrome.

Comment: What server-side language are you using?

Comment: @Dan django, but why?

Comment: does it work if placed inside a form?

Comment: @kinakuta good point. i thought, it would work. but now i put inside form, no success.